# How to download aar and pom file from jitpack.io manually?

Tags: android, android-webview, jitpack

One of my clients has a restricted environment to fetch few transitive dependencies in the Android studio.
One of dependecy [DSBridge-Android](https://github.com/wendux/DSBridge-Android) which is serving by [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/#wendux/DSBridge-Android) is failing to fetch due to network restrictions.

I couldn't find the option to download AAR and POM files manually to put into project directly.

Any one has idea to download depenedencies manually which are serving by https://jitpack.io/

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution!!

Open following URL format in browser then it will download respective jar/aar/pom/etc file. You can find the file path in the log file.

https://jitpack.io/FILE_PATH

### Let me explain with one example:

Let's say I want the AAR and POM file of https://jitpack.io/#wendux/DSBridge-Android

1. Open the log file of the version that you want as follows
   [image]
2. Scroll down till you find the **Files:** section as follows
   [image]
3. Then copy the file path of the required file and open it in the browser with https://jitpack.io/FILE_PATH format. The file will be downloaded now.
   [image]

   Ex: https://jitpack.io/com/github/wendux/DSBridge-Android/v3.0.0/DSBridge-Android-v3.0.0.aar

***Happy Coding!!***